# How to avoid UnicodeEncodeError '\xf8' when scraping table with beautifulsoup

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The script below returns `'UnicodeEncode Error: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xf8' in position 118: ordinal not in range(128)'`

and I cant find a good explanation for it.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

results = {}

for page_num in range(0, 1000, 20):
    address = 'https://www.proff.no/nyetableringer?industryCode=p441&fromDate=22.01.2007&location=Nord-Norge&locationId=N&offset=' + str(page_num) + '&industry=Entreprenører' 

    html = urlopen(address)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    table = soup.find_all(class_='table-condensed')
    output = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
    results[page_num] = output


df = pd.concat([v for v in results.values()], axis = 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the std library to open the url.  This library forces the address to be encoded into ascii.  Hence non ascii characters like ø will throw a Unicode Error.

[Line 1116-1117](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/http/client.py#L1116) of http/client.py

```
    # Non-ASCII characters should have been eliminated earlier
    self._output(request.encode('ascii'))
```

As alternative to urllib.request, the 3rd party requests is great.

```
import requests

address = 'https://www.proff.no/nyetableringer?industryCode=p441&fromDate=22.01.2007&location=Nord-Norge&locationId=N&offset=' + str(page_num) + '&industry=Entreprenører'
html = requests.get(address).text
```